# Open File Dialog in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, openfiledialog

I have created a report in SSRS which is connected to a SQL Server database.

I am using the report as a GUI to show an overview of various tables and diagrams.

I need to include an Open File Dialog (see image) in the report which will allow the user to select a file for import into the database.

[image: Open File Dialog]

Is this possible and if so, how might I accomplish it?

Comment: Do you want to include a "Open File Dialog" in the report its self? Like, clicks link and it opens the dialog asking for a file?

Comment: SSRS is really for reporting and anything outside that really is an unsupported hack. You could add a URL to your report that goes off to a completely seperate web app that contains functionality for uploading files. Depending on how much data input you are doing, you should probably build a web app that references SSRS instead

Comment: @NTDLS: Yes want to include a "Open File Dialog" in the report its self. Thank you for the useful information. Now I have an overview of the boundaries of SSRS.